# How to connect AWS instances to GCP instances without standard ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I have a datastore on aws cloud that I want to access through a GCP instance. While it’s possible for me to shuffle some data back and forth over standard ssh connection. But I’m trying to keep the connection as if they are part of same cloud. How is it possible to do so. ? Are there any external tools to achieve this or any other hack i can adopt.?

Comment: You can setup VPN between a VPC in GCP and AWS.

Comment: ok @Marcin. I tried by building site to site vpn connection and succeeded in doing that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool. If you don't mnid I will make an answer then:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to establish a **VPN connection** between VPSs in AWS and GCP.